# XStream - Tag Creation for xml version

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xstream

I was going through the Xstream tutorials

http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html

How can i add the processing instruction to the xml responses

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n
```

Ex: Xstream gives the response as

```
<message><type>15</type></message>
```

But i would want the instruction also part of the response..

Is there any way i could get it ..

For now am prefixing the string response with this tag which i feel is not the best approach.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about adding the XML **header** to the output, here's how to do that:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n");
xstream.toXML(object, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: I was assigning it to StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n"); and then appending the toXml() output.. I need to return the xml response and not write to the stream.   I believe this is the only way left to add the header.